# Python prefers unassigned local function over built-in function

Tags: python, compatibility

The following Python script works well with Python 2.3 and Python 2.4 (which don't have a built-in definition of `all()`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# vim: set fileencoding=utf-8
# (c) Uwe Kleine-König
# GPLv2

import locale
import sys

f = file(sys.argv[1])
data = f.read()

def len_utf8_char(data):
    if not 'all' in dir(__builtins__):
        def all(seq):
            for i in seq:
                if not i:
                    return False
            return True

    def check_cont(num):
        if all(map(lambda c: ord(c) >= 0x80 and ord(c) <= 0xbf, data[1:num])):
            return num
        else:
            return -1

    if ord(data[0]) < 128:
        # ASCII char
        return 1
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xe0 == 0xc0:
        return check_cont(2)
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xf0 == 0xe0:
        return check_cont(3)
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xf8 == 0xf0:
        return check_cont(4)
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xfc == 0xf8:
        return check_cont(5)
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xfe == 0xfc:
        return check_cont(6)

i = 0
maxl = 0
while i < len(data):
    l = len_utf8_char(data[i:])
    if l < 0:
        prefenc = locale.getpreferredencoding()
        if prefenc not in ('UTF-8', 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'):
            print prefenc
        else:
            print 'ISO-8859-1'
        sys.exit(0)

    if maxl < l:
        maxl = l
    i += l

if maxl > 1:
    print 'UTF-8'
else:
    print 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

Now with Python 2.5 and later this fails as follows:

```
$ python2.5 guess-charmap guess-charmap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guess-charmap", line 43, in <module>
    l = len_utf8_char(data[i:])
  File "guess-charmap", line 30, in len_utf8_char
    return check_cont(2)
  File "guess-charmap", line 21, in check_cont
    if all(map(lambda c: ord(c) >= 0x80 and ord(c) <= 0xbf, data[1:num])):
NameError: free variable 'all' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

Removing the compatibility definition of all fixes the problem for Python 2.5+.
I wonder why Python doesn't pick the builtin `all()` in this case. Can somebody explain?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to detect character encoding. Have you looked at libraries like chardet, which will do this faster and more flexibly? http://chardet.feedparser.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Python parses a function body, it looks for variable names that are used in assignments. All such variables are assumed to be local, unless the `global` variable declaration is used.

The `def all` assigns a value to the variable name `all`. Despite the assignment being inside an `if-block`, `all` is regarded as a local variable in all cases (whether or not the `if-block` is later executed).

When the if-block is not executed, `all` becomes an unbound local variable, thus raising a NameError.

If you move the `if not 'all' ...` block outside the `def len_utf8_char`, then
you will avoid this problem.

Comment: I thought so, but couldn't find that behavior in the the documentation. Probably just didn't find the right search terms.

Answer (score 3):

For the same reason it happens with variables; the compiler has marked it as a local for the function, and so expects it to be a local. If you want to solve this then just do `all = __builtins__.all` in the `else` clause.

Comment: Or just define `all` outside `len_utf8_char`. It's not a closure, there's no reason it needs to be in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the definition of `all` at module level like this:

```
try:
    all
except NameError:
    def all(seq):
        for i in seq:
            if not i:
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you define your function after your all() your still inside the local scope.
Why do you have so many function definitions inside a function?
Why define all() at all?
And why not use a dict for this

```
   if ord(data[0]) < 128:
        # ASCII char
        return 1
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xe0 == 0xc0:
        return check_cont(2)
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xf0 == 0xe0:
        return check_cont(3)
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xf8 == 0xf0:
        return check_cont(4)
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xfc == 0xf8:
        return check_cont(5)
    elif ord(data[0]) & 0xfe == 0xfc:
        return check_cont(6)
```

Infact I would call for a rewrite of this code, its complicated and annoying.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. The rest seems right, but off-topic.